# Combine data within two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames that I want to combine; however, I only want to keep one date.  df1 will be the months from Jan 01, 2013 to Oct, 1, 2016.  df2 will contain the frequency of occurrence of an event.  If there was no event that month, df2 will not show a value.

df1 <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2016-10-01"), by="month"))

```
    df1
    date            Freq 
    1  2013-01-01    0
    2  2013-02-01    0
    3  2013-03-01    0
    4  2013-04-01    0
    5  2013-05-01    0
    ...

    df2
    date            Freq
    1  2013-03-01    1
    2  2013-08-01    2
    3  2014-04-01    5
    4  2014-05-01    2
    5  2014-06-01    5
    ...
```

I want the new data frame to look like the following.

```
    date            Freq 
    1  2013-01-01    0
    2  2013-02-01    0
    3  2013-03-01    1
    4  2013-04-01    0
    5  2013-05-01    0
    6  2013-06-01    0
    7  2013-07-01    0
    8  2013-08-01    2
    9  2013-09-01    0
    ...
```

Comment: try `merge(df1, df2, by="date")`

Comment: The code you show to create `df1` and the version of it you show are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dplyr for its joins,

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2) %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))

## # A tibble: 9 × 2
##         date  Freq
##       <date> <int>
## 1 2013-01-01     0
## 2 2013-02-01     0
## 3 2013-03-01     1
## 4 2013-04-01     0
## 5 2013-05-01     0
## 6 2013-08-01     2
## 7 2014-04-01     5
## 8 2014-05-01     2
## 9 2014-06-01     5
```

or the base equivalent,

```
aggregate(Freq ~ date, merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE), sum)

##         date Freq
## 1 2013-01-01    0
## 2 2013-02-01    0
## 3 2013-03-01    1
## 4 2013-04-01    0
## 5 2013-05-01    0
## 6 2013-08-01    2
## 7 2014-04-01    5
## 8 2014-05-01    2
## 9 2014-06-01    5
```

Order after the fact if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` with `all.x=TRUE` and then set the `NA`'s resulting from the merge to zero:

```
out <- merge(df1,df2,all.x=TRUE)
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
head(out,10)
##         date Freq
##1  2013-01-01    0
##2  2013-02-01    0
##3  2013-03-01    1
##4  2013-04-01    0
##5  2013-05-01    0
##6  2013-06-01    0
##7  2013-07-01    0
##8  2013-08-01    2
##9  2013-09-01    0
##10 2013-10-01    0
```

**Data:** where `df1` is created as in the OP:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2016-10-01"), by="month"))

df1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 
15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 
16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 
16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 
16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 
16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075), class = "Date")), .Names = "date", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), class = "data.frame")
##         date
##1  2013-01-01
##2  2013-02-01
##3  2013-03-01
##4  2013-04-01
##5  2013-05-01
## ...
##42 2016-06-01
##43 2016-07-01
##44 2016-08-01
##45 2016-09-01
##46 2016-10-01

df2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(15765, 15918, 16161, 16191, 
16222), class = "Date"), Freq = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L)), .Names = c("date", 
"Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
##        date Freq
##1 2013-03-01    1
##2 2013-08-01    2
##3 2014-04-01    5
##4 2014-05-01    2
##5 2014-06-01    5
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the data.table way

```
library(data.table)
#Create the data
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- data.table(date=seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2016-10-01"), by="month"))
df2 <- data.table(date=sample(df1$date, size= 10), freq=sample(1:10, 10, replace=T))

#Set keys
setkey(df1, date)
setkey(df2, date)

#data.table magic
df1[df2, freq := freq ]
df1[!df2, freq := 0 ]
df1
```

Result:

```
            date freq
 1: 2013-01-01    3
 2: 2013-02-01    0
 3: 2013-03-01    0
 4: 2013-04-01    0
 5: 2013-05-01    0
 6: 2013-06-01    7
 7: 2013-07-01    0
 ...
```